# Another spam run in progress

Tags: discussion

Somebody is spamming all the sites with "Man United versus Chelsea".  I'm running out of spam flags.  Need some help here.

Comment: Nice try, spammer.

Comment: Which sites are you seeing them on?

Comment: I've got some flags left, but I haven't seen anything so far. Anything I can do to focus my efforts?

Comment: I'm seeing them on StackOverflow, AskUbuntu, Drupal, etc.  I'm looking at the realtime tab and seeing them on sites I can't flag on as well.

Comment: If you're on Chrome, install this extension (https://github.com/honnza/se-spam-helper/blob/master/se-spam-helper.user.js) and go to http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime

Comment: For some reason, I really want to go watch soccer now...

Comment: Somebody flag this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451426/how-to-free-watch-man-united-vs-chelsea-live-streaming-online-26-aug-2013

Comment: @PaulTomblin You posted the link 15 seconds *after* it was deleted.

Comment: @Servy, but 9 minutes after it was posted, so the mods were being slow.  Others I'd flagged after that one were already gone.

Comment: @PaulTomblin That's due to the tags.  That one wasn't tagged to any tags with real views.

Comment: Ok, what's the thing to do here (I don't spend a lot of time on meta) - obviously there is no "right answer", so do I just close it now the spam run seems to be under control?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Closing as "can no longer be reproduced".  Seems close enough.

Answer (score -5):

Perhaps you can just flag 1 for moderator attention, and in the Comments box, ask them to look at the IP address or user name because you suspect it's a SPAM account?  I'm sure the mods will act appropriately.

Comment: They use a different account each time.

Comment: Then ask them to filter on the title.  Tagging dozens of different messages is just gonna drive them bonkers when they can filter on IP/Account/Title, unless all 3 are different every time?

Comment: If you flag them as spam, moderators don't even have to be involved @JohnnyBones. 6 spam flags and the post is gone.

Comment: You don't have to flag it as SPAM, and I wasn't suggesting to do that.  I was suggesting to flag it as something else, which would get a mod involved.  This way the OP wouldn't run out of SPAM flags.

Comment: @JohnnyBones And Bart is saying that that's a bad idea, because then the mods needs to handle the flags.  If they flagged as spam by people who aren't out of flags they can be deleted much quicker than if a mod needs to handle it.

Comment: There is no need to get moderators involved. These are new accounts each time, posting a single spam post from different IPs. IP bans were already ruled out as an option, given that it would involve more or less banning an entire country.

Comment: @Bart content bans seem reasonable, but I guess a userscript is much more flexible when adapting to a changing spam than SE proper. Also, we don't want to give the spammers any hint as to how good are they at avoiding these.

Comment: @JanDvorak With a userscript like yours, the community at large can be pretty effective. I'm sure SO/SE is evaluating their options behind the scenes. They are aware of the issue. But in the mean time the community can do more than enough.

Comment: Is there a link to that userscript? @Bart

Comment: @jgb See the comments on the question itself

Comment: See my comment below the question @jgb. It's quiet now though. Only false positives.

Comment: @Bart - I do like to see these, though, because that lets us clean up after the accounts. Sometimes, more than one of these comes in on a single IP, and we can hit all of them at the same time.

Comment: @Bart I'm not happy with the amount of false positives I produce, but I'm trying to avoid false negatives at all costs. I'm watching the titles, however, looking for places where I can rule out spam. It does seem today's wave is over for a while, though - but there also seems to be a steady stream throughout the day.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, I've had it in a tab during the day. And there are some false positives, but at least, from what I've seen, no false negatives. And I was able to nuke one of the famous troll accounts as well.

Comment: @Bart if you mean the XDOTOOL guy - I've been flagging him as spam, and I haven't seem him for a few days.

Comment: @BradLarson could you clarify to me how that works? If someone were to flag it for moderator attention (non-spam) does the flag still hang around when the rest of us nuke the spam? Because as I understand it, community cleanup of spam means there's no notification for mods any more?

Comment: @Bart - Yes, "other" flags hang around after the deletion of a post. I wish community-spam-flag-deleted posts automatically left some kind of notice for us, because often there's a larger problem that needs to be dealt with there. Often there isn't only one account spamming stuff on an IP, or this isn't the only spam post they've left. Also, our persistent troll has sometimes had one of his posts blown away, but his account left alive to keep on trolling.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay, good to know. Yeah, a "something was nuked by the community" flag/notice might not be a bad idea. And you're right about our trolling friend. One of his posts was blown away pretty rapidly yesterday, but I notified Animuson to take care of his account. Room for improvement.